# Select records where all records with same field have all the same of another field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, case

Is there a way I can reference a column that I created in the select statement without using a subquery?

```
SELECT TVSeason.tvSeasonID, UserHasWatchedTVSeason.*, 
CASE 
    WHEN userhaswatchedtvseason.tvSeasonID IS NULL THEN 'No'
    ELSE 'Yes'
END as watched
FROM TVSeason 
LEFT JOIN UserHasWatchedTVSeason
    ON TVSeason.tvSeasonID = UserHasWatchedTVSeason.tvSeasonID
WHERE watched = 'No'
```

The 'watched' column only exists in the select part of the query.  Obviously I tried the above, column not found.  Im wondering if there is another way I should be doing it - I am trying to avoid cluttering a query with extra subqueries.

Comment: Why not just `WHERE userhaswatchedtvseason.tvSeasonID IS NULL`? Of course, that makes your `watched` psuedo-column redundant

Comment: Complicated story short I will be joining TVSeriesHasTVSeason on it later and need to have Yes / No / Partial as to whether all season in a series have been watched

Comment: Then add that to your question. What you currently have obviously doesn't describe the problem domain at all

Comment: My question is clearly stated - I asked if it is possible to do a WHERE on a SELECT CASE, I didnt ask another question

Comment: You can use a Common Table Expression (CTE), unless you feel that violates your subquery-avoidance moral stance.

Comment: @HABO Thanks for information always interesting in learning new things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a question of scope.  With the way SQL evaluates your query, it doesn't know your column exists yet.

You'll either need to do as you suggested and create a sub-query to re-use your derived column as a variable or you'll need to copy-paste the logic that the derived column represents into your case statment.

Comment: Thanks.  This is the validation I was looking for.